# LARAVEL -> Why try catch not work in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have code in RouteServiceProvider:

```
$router->bind('user', function ($value) {
    try{
        throw (new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        exit('nott');
    }
});
```

and I don not geting output

```
nott
```

I am getting

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
NotFoundHttpException in RouteServiceProvider.php line 75:
...
```

EDITED:
This works:

```
$router->bind('user', function ($value) {
    try{
        throw (new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException);
    }catch(\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException $e){
        exit('addd');
    }
});
```

But this not works:

```
$router->bind('user', function ($value) {
    try{
        return (new User)->findOrFail(122);
    }catch(\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException $e){
        exit('addd');
    }
});
```

Comment: Off topic, but in general it's considered bad practice to catch the general `Exception` class; you should instead do a catch on the specific type(s) of exception that you anticipate getting. (btw: the practice of catching the general `Exception` class is jokingly called "Pokemon exception handling" -- because you're gonna catch 'em all)

Comment: The problem you're getting is not related to Laravel, it's related to Namespacing. When you use namespaces in a PHP class, you must then reference the full namespace of all classes it uses. Even plain PHP ones in the top-level namespace need a backslash to reference their namespace. Or you can tell the class to `use` them, and then you won't need the namespace. (the same applies to the Symphony exception class you're using, and to any other class; you can have a `use` statement for them at the top of your class, then you don't need to give the full namespace in your code body. Much neater.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$router->bind('user', function ($value) {
    try{
        throw (new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException);
    }catch(\Exception $e){
        exit('nott');
    }
});
```

OR

```
use Exception; //on top

    $router->bind('user', function ($value) {
        try{
            throw (new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException);
        }catch(Exception $e){
            exit('nott');
        }
    });
```

i think now you understand what you missing.

Comment: OP probably has these codes in the `routes.php` file of Laravel which doesn't have any namespace expression, thus the `use Exception;` part is unnecessary.

Comment: try to catch(\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e) because findorfail throw model not found exception.